# can't figure out this non static member reference error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm new to C++ and trying to figure this out.  When I compile, I get the error `a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object`.  What's the correct way of writing the code?  This is what I have where `numShapes` is giving me the error.

```
class Application
private:
     int numShapes;
public:
     Shapes * shapes[numShapes];
```

I then have this in another header as my virtual base class, if that's the correct term.

```
class Shapes
{
    virtual void draw(char letter);
    virtual ~Shapes() {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The code `Shapes * shapes[numShapes];` is requesting the compiler to reserve numShapes amount of space. The problem is that it does not have a known value at compile time. So either make `numshapes` a constant, or look into dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: I tried changing it to dynamic array using this

        Shapes * shapes = new Shapes[numShapes];

but now it gives the error: array of abstract class "Shapes" is not allowed: function "Shapes::draw" is a pure virtual function

Comment: not sure what you mean. The main thing is that the value of nuShapes should be known at compile time. Or don't use an array rather use one of std:: containers. e. g. std::vector

Comment: @brisk172 The dynamic array error is because you didn't define draw().

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 Shapes * shapes[numShapes];
```

I suggest the use of:

```
 std::vector<Shapes*> shapes;
```

Remove `numShapes` altogether since you can get the size from `shapes`.

Initialize `shapes` in the constructor. Something along the lines of the following should work.

```
Application::Application(std::size_t numShapes) : shapes(numShapes, nullptr) {}
```

Comment: That worked, but now it gives another type of error in a different .cpp file where I have  shapes = new Shapes *[numShapes];   It gives the error no operator "=" matches these operands.  What would be the right operand?

Comment: @brisk172, that question indicates to me that you should get a basic understanding of `std::vector`. If you don't understand how to use `std::vector`, please ignore my suggestion.